# How can I get this echo to function?

Tags: php, echo, multiple-choice

Using this code how can you make it only echo out the radio or checkbox if you have a b c d answers or a b answers.  On my quiz its going to be a b c d and a (true) b (false) answers. To finish my quiz this is the only thing stopping me from finishing it. My question might not be to the point but I tried to get it ask close to what I did done.  Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
    //retreive questions from database and put into question box

    $query2 = "SELECT `QuestionId`, `Question`, `Opt1`, `Opt2`, `Opt3`, `Opt4`,`Answer` FROM `pf_questions`";

    $question2 = mysql_query($query2);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($question2)){

        $id         = $row['QuestionId'];
        $question   = $row['Question'];
        $opt1       = $row['Opt1'];
        $opt2       = $row['Opt2'];
        $opt3       = $row['Opt3'];
        $opt4       = $row['Opt4'];
        $answer     = $row["Answer"];




    ?>
    <div id="ContainerQuestion">
        <span class="Question">Question <?php echo $id; ?>. <?php echo $question; ?></span>

            <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'a')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?>  value="a"> <?php echo $opt1; ?> </p>
            <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'b')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?> value="b"> <?php echo $opt2; ?> </p>
            <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'c')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?> value="c"> <?php echo $opt3; ?> </p>

            <p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'd')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?> value="d"> <?php echo $opt4; ?> </p>


    </div>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql_*` functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/871050)

Comment: Are you trying to show only two radio buttons in the case that Opt3 and Opt4 fields are blank?

Comment: @jedwards yes if the question has an a b c d then I want it to show the question with the four choices and if the question has a b then no c d should show.  So yes in your question about the Opt3 & Opt4 field are blank.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thats a great point, but it's worth offering him help with solving this query/logic before introducing broader DB abstraction. Hopefully he'll take it on board!

Comment: Ok update ... The radio is works fine with the help from everyone that gave me input.  Thanks!

Comment: @nickhar: mysqli isn't necessary "broader database abstraction", it's called "common sense".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha But it's only common sense and a better option to many  when they've seen the other side of the fence! I think we're violently agreeing that it's the right way!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're asking.
you want to wrap each line in an "if" clause.
For example:

```
<?php if( isset ($opt3) ) { ?>

<p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'c')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?> value="c"> <?php echo $opt3; ?> </p>

<?php } 
      if( isset ($opt4) ) { ?>

<p><input type=radio name='q<?php echo $id; ?>' <?=( $answer  == 'd')?("checked='checked'"):(""); ?> value="d"> <?php echo $opt4; ?> </p>

<?php } ?>
```

somewhat ugly hack but it should work and you get the idea.

Comment: An empty string is not null, and should return `TRUE` when passed to `isset()`.

Comment: I made the assumption that a NULL Field in his database should be what he has for these cases.  Otherwise you can add `&& ($opt3)` inside the if statements to make sure not blank.

Comment: @user16081 I will try and also would like to Thank everyone for your input on my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably replace your `while` loop with something like the following (untested):

```
$answerFields = array('Opt1'=>'a', 'Opt2'=>'b', 'Opt3'=>'c', 'Opt4'=>'d');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($question2)){
    $id         = $row['QuestionId'];
    $question   = $row['Question'];

    // Print Question
    printf('<div id="ContainerQuestion">');
    printf('<span class="Question">Question %s. %s</span>', $id, $question);

    // Print Answers
    foreach($answerFields as $field=>$ans)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($field, $row) && $row[$field])
        {
            $checked = ($row["Answer"] == $ans) ? 'checked' : '';
            printf('<p><input type="radio" name="%s" %s value="%s">%s</p>', 
                $id, $checked, $ans, $row[$field]);
        }
    }
}
```

If the answer field in your database (Opt1, Opt, etc.) is not set, or an empty string, the `<p>` containing the response shouldn't be printed.

This solution allows you to extend your application to cases where 3/4 responses are filled and 1/4 is empty.  It also cleans up your code a bit by using `printf` statements instead of hopping between inline php and html.

Lastly, obligatory note pointing out the important comment about prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also how can I make it where when they submit it; it sends the results to my email with the question and there answer and the right answer.  Like example: Joe Doe quiz results 1. Question - Answer: A. true or  C. the guy coding it - Right Answer: B. false or C: the guy coding it. and maybe a you got 10/20 right.  If you know what I mean.

Comment: Oh man, thats a completely separate question.  If this worked, let us know, and consider looking into the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, and creating a separate question here if you run into trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the help using your help got it to function right Thanks again. I will look into it and try something out before I ask about this agian " Also how can I make it where when they submit it; it sends the results to my email with the question and there answer and the right answer. Like example: Joe Doe quiz results 1. Question - Answer: A. true or C. the guy coding it - Right Answer: B. false or C: the guy coding it. and maybe a you got 10/20 right. If you know what I mean."

Comment: I almost forgot to ask this question in my post earlier couldn't get the <form action="" method=""><input type="submit"></form> to work with the coding above.

Comment: Sorry, what?  What do you want/ what are you trying to do?

Comment: when your done with the quiz and then you hit the submit button it take you somewhere. Meaning sending the email.

Comment: Right, you're looking for something like: `<form action="handler.php" method="post">`.  The action is the filename of the form handler and the method is either "post" or "get", depending on how your handler is written.

Comment: how would I add the <form action="handler.php" method="post"> and the <input type="submit"> in the above code because I getting errors

Comment: Wrap all the inputs in a `<form ...>` and `</form>` tag, including your `<input type="submit">` button.

Comment: Ok thanks again for your help. I got the submit button on without any errors.